# Spring JPA Hibernate Auto Populate Audit Fields (Create ID / Timestamp etc)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have an entity class that I would like to audit:

```
@Data    // Lombok for getters/setters
@Entity
public class EventEntity {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  @CreatedBy
  private String createdId;
  private LocalDateTime creationTimestamp;  // @CreatedDate or @CreationTimestamp
  @LastModifiedBy
  private String modifiedId;
  private LocalDateTime lastModifiedTimestamp; // @LastModifiedDate or @UpdateTimestamp
  // other fields
}
```

And I have a `JpaRepository` for database operations:

```
public interface EventRepository extends JpaRepository<EventEntity, Long> {
  // Empty
}
```

There are these annotations and I'm not sure which date annotation I should be using:

```
org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedBy
org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate
org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp

org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedBy
org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate
org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp
```

For The `@CreatedBy` / `@LastModifiedBy` fields I've implemented `org.springframework.data.domain.AuditorAware` as per documentation that just returns a constant:

```
@Component("auditor")
public class CustomAuditorAware implements AuditorAware<String> {

@Override
  public Optional<String> getCurrentAuditor() {
     return Optional.of("ID");
  }
}
```

And I've enabled JPA Auditing:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing("auditor")
public class AppConfig {
}
```

Here how I've tried persisting to the DB:

```
EventEntity eventEntity = eventRepository.findById("ID") // returns Optional
    .orElse(new EventEntity());
eventEntity.setSomeField("New Value");
eventRepository.save(eventEntity);
```

(Please correct me on the hibernate entity states if I am wrong below)

### Situation 1: EventEntity is new

The no args constructor is called and now the `eventEntity` is in **transient** state. The `save()` method executes a `select` query followed by an `update` query, which will error out with this message:

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CREATED_ID'
```

### Situation 2:  EventEntity exists already

The `eventEntity` is now in the **detached** state. The audit fields are already populated. The `save()` method executes a `update` query, but none of the audit fields are changed.

### Ideal Solution

I don't really care about any of the existing data fields, I just want to update if it exists already. So ideally I won't call the `findById()` method. I'll create an `EventEntity` in the **transient** state and it will retain the `createdId` and `creationTimestamp` data. So almost like above:

```
EventEntity eventEntity = new EventEntity();
eventEntity.setSomeField("New Value");
eventRepository.save(eventEntity);
```

## My Problem

None of the auditing fields are working as I expect it to. How do I get it working?

Which audit date annotations should I be using? The one from Spring JPA or from hibernate? I've tried both sets with no luck. What's the difference between each?

**Versions**:

- Spring Boot 2.1
- Hibernate 5.3.10.final

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the following annotation in the entity class

```
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
```